# Permutation of integers from an array given lengh

Tags: algorithm, recursion, permutation

I was interviewed a problem and after that I tested my code, found it wrong.
Not good at recursion. But I can't figure out the problem.

The question is: Given an array range from 0 ~ 9, and a length, for example, 3; generate
all permutations of integers from the given array in given length.
So, for the example:
The permutation should be: 012, 013, 014,..., 345, 346...
Below is my java code, where's the problem? (I think it's the index or the offset part)
And, if there's any better solution!

```
public void NumPermutation(int[] list, int offset, int[] temp, int index){
    if(index == 4){
       printarray(temp);
    }

    for(int count = offset; count < list.length; count++){
        temp[index++] = list[count];
        int te = list[offset];
        list[offset] = list[count];
        list[count] = te;
        NumPermutation(list, offset, temp, index);
        index -= 1;
    }
}

public void test(int len){
    int[] list = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    int[] temp = new int[4];
    int index = 0, offset = 0;
    NumPermutation(list, offset, temp,index);
}
```

The problem is that, the offset may increase each time and 
it can't even reach the number to the end.

Comment: Where is the declaration of `count`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- Pass `offset+1` to the recursive call.
- Return in the if-statement.
- Reverse your swap after the recursive call.
- Replace the `4` with `temp.length` for a more generic solution.
- Also preferably replace `index++`, `index`, `index -= 1` with `index`, `index + 1` and nothing.

Which results in this code: (replaced `printarray` with a standard print method, assuming this is Java)

```java
public static void NumPermutation(int[] list, int offset, int[] temp, int index){
    if(index == temp.length) {
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));
       return;
    }

    for(int count = offset; count < list.length; count++){
        temp[index] = list[count];

        // swap
        int te = list[offset];
        list[offset] = list[count];
        list[count] = te;

        NumPermutation(list, offset + 1, temp, index + 1);

        // reverse swap
        te = list[offset];
        list[offset] = list[count];
        list[count] = te;
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/abhOGY).

Comment: But I don't understand why reverse swap at the end?

Comment: @JudyJiang Because, if you don't, you mess up the order of the elements when recursing. And when you run through the for-loop, you want to get all different elements (otherwise you repeat values), but, since the order changes (and doesn't change back), this is no longer guaranteed. (You can check what happens when taking it out - it keeps repeating `0,1,2,X` and `0,1,9,X`, instead of doing `0,1,3,X`, `0,1,4,X`, etc.).